# Need batch file to create folder every 24 hours

Tags: batch-file

I'm using Windows 7. I want folder has to be created every 24 hours automatically. I have done some basic research on this but I couldn't get the batch file. Please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [scheduled task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/schedule-a-task) for that. Write a batch file that creates your folder, then add it as a scheduled task.

Comment: or, to create it within Batch: `schtasks /create /?`

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use the "Scheduled Task" as stated by @spaceknarf to run your batch 24-hourly or you can directly run a batch on Win7 and above with the following commands::

```
mkdir FolderName
timeout /t 86400 /nobreak
```

86400 = 24 * 60 * 60 (24 hours in seconds)

/nobreak = Ignore key presses and wait specified time

The complete batch file::

```
@echo off
cls
:start
mkdir FolderName
echo FolderName Created
timeout /t 86400 /nobreak
goto start
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also the [AT](http://ss64.com/nt/at.html) command for setting things to go off at certain times.